# Twitter API works locally, but is spotty on remote server

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I wrote a script that pulls the current top Twitter trends using cURL and it works 100% of the time locally but when I FTP it up to my mediatemple server it seems to only work sometimes. Is this caused by Twitter? Mediatemple? Some error in my code?

EDIT: How can I cache content in a flat-file?

Comment: What is the error when it fails?

Comment: Perhaps you're hitting a rate limit from your remote server?

Comment: @joet3ch, no error, just nothing is returned.

Comment: @zigdon, I don't think so, it's just me viewing the page.

Comment: I second the rate limit thing, how much traffic do you get? You could try setting up some simple caching around it. IE a flat file cache that refreshes once a minute. Are you getting it via XML or JSON?

Comment: It's just a little project I've been playing with, I really doubt anyone else has visited it. I'm getting it via JSON and decoding with PHP. What are some simple, good ways to cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code works sometimes that suggests it is not a problem with your code so there are two logical areas for potential blame:

**1) Web Server Load**

This could be your server is to bogged down. If the server (not just your site - consider this if your on shared hosting) is experiencing a heavy load then it may take your server too long to complete the curl request. to combat this try and increase the timeout time on the request using the following:

```
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT
```

**2) Twitter Rate Limmit**

Twitter limits the number of API calls you can make from one authorized account per hour (I believe the number is around 100ish - check their API Documentation) If you are hitting this limit you will be declined further calls until the 1 hour anniversary of the first call. To combat this have either a cron job run the curl at a set interval and cache the result in a text file or database or store the time of each request made and use an IF to only allow one request every 2 or 3 mins, cache the results and pull the results from the cache.

Making a call to the twitter API every time there is a page load is a waste of resources, bandwith and could reduce page load time.